# How to run xcodebuild command in shell iOS

Tags: ios, bash, shell, xcodebuild

I want to run this simple command via a shell script

i.e

```
xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Shujaat’s iPad' clean test
```

I ran above command via command line and is working fine.

here is my output log

```
    === CLEAN TARGET AFNetworking OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework.dSYM


=== CLEAN TARGET Alamofire OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework



=== CLEAN TARGET Firebase OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Firebase.framework.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Firebase.framework.dSYM



=== CLEAN TARGET OAuth2iOS OF PROJECT OAuth2 WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework

=== CLEAN TARGET Flurry-iOS-SDK OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flurry_iOS_SDK.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Flurry_iOS_SDK.framework


=== CLEAN TARGET ForecastIOClient-ForecastIOClient OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.bundle
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.bundle


=== CLEAN TARGET Kingfisher OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.framework

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.framework.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.framework.dSYM

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/Kingfisher.build

=== CLEAN TARGET SwiftyJSON OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftyJSON.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftyJSON.framework


=== CLEAN TARGET Starscream OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Starscream.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Starscream.framework

=== CLEAN TARGET ForecastIOClient OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.framework

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.framework.dSYM
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.framework.dSYM

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.build
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/ForecastIOClient.build

=== CLEAN TARGET Pods-jamesAppV2 OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods_jamesAppV2.framework
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Pods_jamesAppV2.framework

=== CLEAN TARGET jamesAppV2 OF PROJECT jamesAppV2 WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'JamesApp/Info.plist'.

Clean.Remove clean /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app
    builtin-rm -rf /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app

** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

2016-05-05 13:09:29.199 xcodebuild[19632:107456] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (87B2511E-F180-4544-ACFF-1A2C85F77D99) Beginning test session 87B2511E-F180-4544-ACFF-1A2C85F77D99 with Xcode 7D175 on target <DVTiOSDevice: 0x7fea65942410> {
        deviceSerialNumber:         DMRJ2Z2UDJ8T
        identifier:                 3515e210981cf6cd0d1b3539f8bf63617ba19372
        deviceClass:                iPad
        deviceName:                 Shujaat’s iPad
        deviceIdentifier:           3515e210981cf6cd0d1b3539f8bf63617ba19372
        productVersion:             9.3.1
        buildVersion:               13E238
        deviceSoftwareVersion:      9.3.1 (13E238)
        deviceArchitecture:         armv7f
        deviceTotalCapacity:        13446778880
        deviceAvailableCapacity:    8529731584
        deviceIsTransient:          NO
        ignored:                    NO
        deviceIsBusy:               NO
        deviceIsActivated:          YES
        deviceActivationState:      Activated
        deviceType:                 <DVTDeviceType:0x7fea6547f1d0 Xcode.DeviceType.iPhone>
        supportedDeviceFamilies:    (
    1,
    2
)
        applications:              (null)
        provisioningProfiles:      (null)
        activityProgress:          -2
        activityTitle:             
        hasInternalSupport:        NO
        isSupportedOS:             YES
        developerDiskMountError:   (null)
(null)
    } (9.3.1 (13E238))
2016-05-05 13:09:29.265 xcodebuild[19632:107459]  IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test session to:
/Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Logs/Test/D570C24D-9119-4CC6-82D5-69A1CDAD50C1/Session-2016-05-05_13:09:29-0cB4I6.log
=== BUILD TARGET OAuth2iOS OF PROJECT OAuth2 WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies

Write auxiliary files
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/module.modulemap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OAuth2iOS-OutputFileMap.json
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/unextended-module-overlay.yaml
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/swift-overrides.hmap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2-generated-files.hmap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2-own-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/OAuth2.LinkFileList
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/unextended-module.modulemap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2-project-headers.hmap
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/DerivedSources
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/DerivedSources/OAuth2_vers.c
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2-all-target-headers.hmap
write-file /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Intermediates/OAuth2.build/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2iOS.build/OAuth2.hmap

Create product structure
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework/Modules
/bin/mkdir -p /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework/Headers

ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework/Info.plist OAuth2/Info.plist
    cd /Users/qadirhussain/Desktop/lebijou-jamesapp/OAuth2
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/bin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/qadirhussain/Desktop/lebijou-jamesapp/OAuth2/OAuth2/Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos -o /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/OAuth2.framework/Info.plist
:))



Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: ***********************

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign *********************** --timestamp=none /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app/PlugIns/jamesAppV2Tests.xctest

CodeSign /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app
    cd /Users/qadirhussain/Desktop/lebijou-jamesapp
    export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/qadirhussain/.rvm/bin"

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: ***********************"

    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign *********************** --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --timestamp=none /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app
/Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app: replacing existing signature

MDMCreateDeltaDirectory:1920 calling MDMDirectoryDiff with:
state->old_bundle: /var/folders/3h/1gxh7rf94z9c_f2z13_pxp9m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/3bc83beb2a7461da70ae62f5027faece/3515e210981cf6cd0d1b3539f8bf63617ba19372/jamesAppV2.app
state->new_bundle: /Users/qadirhussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jamesAppV2-cszkwmryotqiysalbeblxpdpqbcr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/jamesAppV2.app
state->dst_bundle: /var/folders/3h/1gxh7rf94z9c_f2z13_pxp9m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/jamesAppV2.app.lXkCLx/jamesAppV2.app_sparse.ipa/Payload//jamesAppV2.app, binaryDiff flag: FALSE
    dst_ipa: /var/folders/3h/1gxh7rf94z9c_f2z13_pxp9m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/jamesAppV2.app.lXkCLx/jamesAppV2.app_sparse.ipa
__MDMDirectoryDiff_block_invoke37:1473 calling writeDictToFile with: /var/folders/3h/1gxh7rf94z9c_f2z13_pxp9m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/jamesAppV2.app.lXkCLx/jamesAppV2.app_sparse.ipa/ManifestCache.plist
writeDictToFile:1278 ==== Successfully wrote Manifest cache to /var/folders/3h/1gxh7rf94z9c_f2z13_pxp9m0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/All/Xcode/EmbeddedAppDeltas/jamesAppV2.app.lXkCLx/jamesAppV2.app_sparse.ipa/ManifestCache.plist
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Connecting Socket didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
battery_level_percentage 56
Activate our screensaver
idleTimerDisabled true
applicationWillEnterForeground
2016-05-05 13:05:53.923 jamesAppV2[245:26657] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_160_7.1.1] 
applicationDidBecomeActive
1
13:05:55.145 jamesAppV2[245:26679] _XCT_testBundleReadyWithProtocolVersion:minimumVersion: reply received
13:05:55.470 jamesAppV2[245:26679] _IDE_startExecutingTestPlanWithProtocolVersion:16
Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2016-05-05 13:05:55.593
Test Suite 'jamesAppV2Tests.xctest' started at 2016-05-05 13:05:55.601
Test Suite 'James_App_Tests' started at 2016-05-05 13:05:55.606
Test Case '-[jamesAppV2Tests.James_App_Tests testExample]' started.
Test Case '-[jamesAppV2Tests.James_App_Tests testExample]' passed (0.010 seconds).
Test Case '-[jamesAppV2Tests.James_App_Tests testPerformanceExample]' started.
2
<unknown>:0: Test Case '-[jamesAppV2Tests.James_App_Tests testPerformanceExample]' measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.000, relative standard deviation: 76.169%, values: [0.000028, 0.000009, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006, 0.000006], performanceMetricID:com.apple.XCTPerformanceMetric_WallClockTime, baselineName: "", baselineAverage: , maxPercentRegression: 10.000%, maxPercentRelativeStandardDeviation: 10.000%, maxRegression: 0.100, maxStandardDeviation: 0.100
Test Case '-[jamesAppV2Tests.James_App_Tests testPerformanceExample]' passed (0.496 seconds).
Test Suite 'James_App_Tests' passed at 2016-05-05 13:05:56.121.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.506 (0.516) seconds
Test Suite 'jamesAppV2Tests.xctest' passed at 2016-05-05 13:05:56.127.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.506 (0.525) seconds
Test Suite 'All tests' passed at 2016-05-05 13:05:56.131.
     Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 0.506 (0.538) seconds
** TEST SUCCEEDED **
```

but from shell script its throwing an error.

```
xcodebuild: error: Scheme jamesAppV2 is not currently configured for the test action.
```

here is my simple one liner shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
#My First Script

xcodebuild -workspace jamesAppV2.xcworkspace -scheme jamesAppV2 -configuration Debug -destination 'platform=iOS,name=Shujaat’s iPad' clean test
```

this looks strange to me. 
Is there any mistake in the shell xcodebuild command?

Comment: How do you run the command `xcodebuild ...`? Do you have to source some files beforehand, set some variables, something extra? Maybe you will have those in your script.

Comment: I have given my shell script above. and executing it via terminal like $sudo sh my_filename.sh

Comment: OK so this is being run by `root` then. When you run the command manually, do you also run it with `sudo`?

Comment: no I run without sudo .

Comment: OMG without sudo its working :O

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate, because it is another issue. Anyway, I posted an answer to make the solution clear. Accepting it will make it even clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we saw in the comments, the problem here is that you were running your script with `sudo`. This means that the user executing it is `root` instead of your user. This means completely different environments and multiple other settings.

So to mimic what you are doing in the shell, just run the script normally without any mention of `sudo`:

```
./script.sh   # no sudo
```

Comment: This command has stopped working after Xcode 14 can you help